# Augmented Reality (Display Animated Object)

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality

I am trying to build an Augmented Reality App 
but I can't find any  **method to display the .dae file**  which is an animated object 
is there any helpful tutorial about this? Using Xcode or NinevehGL. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create augmented reality applications using cocod2d. There is a tutorial here http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/introduction-to-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone As this is the simplest way I can think of implementing this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link to a FBX converter](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=10775855). You can change collada dae files to FBX and then use the tutorial [here](https://dev.metaio.com/augmented-reality-developer-news/article/this-is-the-test-entry/) using the metaio sdk to code an AR app in Xcode.